# Silent installation of Apache Tomcat

Tags: tomcat8, tomcat8.5

I want to install Apache Tomcat 8.5.11 silently to a specific
directory using a batch file.

I have tried below command:

**apache-tomcat-8.5.11.exe /S /D="D:\softwares\Tomcat"**

The installation happens silently, but it is installed to 
C:\Program Files\ instead of the location provided using /D option.

Is there any other configuration that is needed ?

Comment: Does the specified directory exist? Not sure if tomcat requires this, but you could give it a try

Comment: Yes, I have created the directory and the user has write permission as well.

Answer (score 3):

Got this resolved by removing double quotes in the path
For e.g., this works:

apache-tomcat-8.5.11.exe /S /D=D:\softwares\Tomcat

Also works for directory names with spaces.